# How to integrate a pre-FTL and a pre-sapient civilization in the same system into your Stellaris empire?

Tags: stellaris

I have a system within my borders that has both a pre-sapient civilization and a pre-FTL civilization. I'd like to integrate both of them into my empire. I know I can uplift the pre-FTL civ and then integrate them after a while, but I worry that if I uplift it, it will settle the pre-sapient life form's planet.

Can I give them sapience and then advance one or the other without them fighting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first colonize the pre-sapients, then uplift them. They will become just another species in your empire. Then you can move to integrating pre-FTL civ. You can infiltrate them, then they will also join your empire right away. Or you can enlighten them. Then they'll became your protectorate which you can integrate later. Or simply conquer them) They'll forget it in a decade or two) No infighting between these two species in either case.

Here is the wiki page about it: https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Pre-FTL_species

Comment: Alright, I'll try this out, if it works I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Alright so I colonized the pre-sapient's planet and uplifted them, I can't go the infiltration route because the largest faction would hate me for going off of passive study so I need to enlighten the pre-FTL species now. I'm curious however if you know what will happen to my colony when they become their own civilization. Will it become their colony with my citizens (including the uplifted species)?

Comment: @Rob Rose You will definitely remain in control over the colonized planet. It is possible for 2 empires to have planets in the same system. Remember war declaration menu - you chose "cede planet", not cede system. The contested system with multiple owners will be shown in striped pattern on the galaxy map.

Answer (score -1):

I'm in the process of doing this myself right now.

After the pre-FTL civ (Steam Age, in my case) reached FTL, they showed as a "protectorate" and there was a diplomatic communication option like any other AI.  They'll start with a high opinion of you which will attenuate over time, though I believe trust tends to increase.  After 3600 days (presume this to be 10 years) you can integrate them into your empire -- the user interface shows you the relevant date when the 3600d will be up.